# How to fix "TraitError: The 'input' trait of a ... instance is 'read only'."

Tags: python, macports, enthought, mayavi

I have always preferred the more pythonic tvtk over vtk's raw Python API, but with the latest versions I get from MacPorts, I have the problem that basic things don't work anymore.  The following snippet is taken from the [tvtv documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/tvtk/README.html#basic-usage):

```
from tvtk.api import tvtk
cs = tvtk.ConeSource()
cs.resolution = 36
m = tvtk.PolyDataMapper()
m.input = cs.output # <== fails here
a = tvtk.Actor()
a.mapper = m
p = a.property
p.representation = 'w'
print p.representation
```

With every initialization of 'input' traits, I get an error like

```
TraitError: The 'input' trait of a PolyDataMapper instance is 'read only'.
```

I have found many similar questions, bug reports etc., but they all point to changes related to VTK 6 (`SetInputData` and `SetInputConnection` instead of `SetInput`), which [should be supported in Mayavi 4.4.2](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/74), and I am having:

```
vtk @6.3.0_0+python27 (active)
py27-traits @4.5.0_0 (active)
py27-traitsui @5.0.0_0 (active)
py27-apptools @4.3.0_0 (active)
py27-envisage @4.4.0_0 (active)
py27-pyface @5.0.0_0+pyqt4 (active)
py27-mayavi @4.4.3_0 (active)
```

The `PolyDataMapper` has the following input-traits:

```
'input': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x11b23a260>,
'input_algorithm': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x119516520>,
'input_as_data_set': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x11b230470>,
'input_connection': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x119516310>,
'input_executive': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x1195165d0>,
'input_information': <traits.traits.CTrait at 0x119516680>,
```

Answer (score 5):

Mayavi supports both VTK 5.10 and VTK 6.x, which have internally a different API to configure to the pipeline. The `tvtk` package has a common API that supports both versions for portability.

Changing:

```
m.input = cs.output # <== fails here
```

to:

```
from tvtk.common import configure_input
tvtk.configure_input(m, cs) # <== will work
```

Ref: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/master/tvtk/common.py#L79

Comment: Indirectly, the above contains the answer I was looking for, namely the "correct" new API.  I am not interested in VTK 5 support, yet I did not see how the code needs to be adapted.  From the link, it appears as if there is no trait for the non-connection case, but `set_input_data(some_data)` is what I was missing.